# Right to left mask input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following mask input in jQuery:

```
  $("#id_Account").mask("9999",{placeholder:"0"})
```

The current behaviour of this textbox is to have zeros as placeholder to type the numbers that i just need and then fill the rest with 0's after typing enter. 
But I would like to fill the with 0's at left side, not at right side after typing.

For example, I have in the texbox "0000" (or just blank), then I type "12", then the textbox is showing this value: "1200", but that i really want is this value: "0012"

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is a feature that the plugin doesn't support. It's simple enough to implement yourself, why not create it (and send a PR to the plugin to add it)?

Here's something to start you out:

```
function prependMask(input,mask) {
  var m_len = mask.length, i_len = input.length; // get |mask| - |input|

  if i_len <= m_len {
    return Array(m_len - i_len).join(mask[0]) + input; // prepend mask of length (|m| - |input|) to input
  } else { 
    return input; // no need for mask
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented myself with something like this:

```
<input name="myaccount1" type="text" style="text-align:right" onchange="mask_account(this)">
```

This is the function:

```
function mask_account(field_account){
            var qty_chars = field_account.value.length;
            var zeros = ''
            for (i=0; i < 4 - qty_chars; i++ ){
                zeros= zeros + '0';
            }

            var new_value = zeros + field_account.value;
            field_account.value = new_value;
        }
```