# Right to Left input mask

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the digitalbush input mask for time. Currently, I have it set up as 0:00:00. When you enter the numbers, it populates from left to right. So adding a 1 would result in 1:00:00 ... adding another 1 results in 1:10:00. I would like it to go from right to left so a 1 would result in 0:00:01 .... adding another 1 would result in 0:00:11. 

I have attached dir="rtl" to my input, which on it's own just formats the placeholder text to the right, doesn't affect the way the numbers are input. When I add numericInput:true, the numbers populate from right to left, exactly as I want, but it doesn't keep the placeholder values - it goes to _:**:**.

Could someone please provide direction/know if this is possible? I found this [Right to left mask input with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476344/right-to-left-mask-input-with-jquery) but can't seem to make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using RobinHerbots input mask.

My html input block:

```
<input type = "text" name = "result" id = "result" placeholder= "0:00:00" dir="rtl">
```

The jquery formatting:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#result").inputmask("9:99:99",{numericInput:true, placeholder:"0"});
});
```

The result of this is a placeholder 0:00:00 and when you type "1" it results in 0:00:01. Then a "23" you get 00:01:23 and so on...